# emscripten ASSERTIONS=1 generates linker error "Referencing global in another module!"

Tags: c++, linker, emscripten

When I set "-s ASSERTIONS=1" then linker will fail with lots of "Referencing global in another module!" messages, e.g.:

> Referencing global in another module! [16 x i8]*
>   @_ZZN8nlohmann10basic_jsonINSt3__23mapENS1_6vectorENS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbxydS7_NS_14adl_serializerEE13escape_stringERKS9_E6hexify
>   ; ModuleID =
>   'src/ui_lib/logic/libcommands.bc'
>   [16 x i8]*
>   @_ZZN8nlohmann10basic_jsonINSt3__23mapENS1_6vectorENS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbxydS7_NS_14adl_serializerEE13escape_stringERKS9_E6hexify
>   ; ModuleID =
>   'src/ui_lib/curves.bc'
>   Referencing global in another module!
>   %"struct.ui::EmscriptenBindingInitializer_uicurves"*
>   @_ZN5boost6detail15optional_detail13none_instanceINS_6none_tEE8instanceE
>   ; ModuleID =
>   'src/ui_lib/logic/libcommands.bc'
>   %"struct.ui::EmscriptenBindingInitializer_uicurves"*
>   @_ZN5boost6detail15optional_detail13none_instanceINS_6none_tEE8instanceE
>   ; ModuleID =
>   'src/ui_lib/curves.bc'

It happens when I use instances of nlohmann::json (https://github.com/nlohmann/json) in multiple translation units.

Is that a bug or a feature? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an emscripten bug: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/5008

Fix is very easy: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/pull/5021/commits/1b0d41d1845015491a52da2cb9f7da7dfe3acf44